# Focus of paper-menu conflict with tap event

Tags: javascript, html, focus, dom-events, polymer-1.0

Following the release of Polymer 1.0, I have tried to update an application I was working on. Despite the quite complete doc provided: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html, I am still encountering some issues, in particular the following one.

I am using paper-menu element along side with the paper-menu-button one.
The goal is to have a standard menu with on each paper-item a paper-menu-button allowing me to customize the corresponding section.
As code is always clearer here an example of what I am trying to achieve (I simplified it by using basic demo from polymer site)

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>paper-menu demo</title>

    <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-menu/paper-submenu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-styles/demo-pages.html">

    <style is="custom-style">
        paper-item {
            --paper-item: {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            ;
        }
        
        paper-icon-button{
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            background-color: black;
        }
        
        .sublist {
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body unresolved>
    
    <template id="Demo" is="dom-bind">
        <h4>Sub-menu</h4>
        <div class="horizontal-section">
            <paper-menu>
                <paper-submenu>
                    <paper-item class="menu-trigger">
                        Topics
                        <span class="flex layout horizontal end-justified">
                            <paper-menu-button on-tap="test">
                                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
                                <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
                                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[letters]]" as="letter">
                                        <paper-item>[[letter]]</paper-item>
                                    </template>
                                </paper-menu>
                            </paper-menu-button>
                        </span>
                    </paper-item>
                    <paper-menu class="menu-content sublist">
                        <paper-item>Topic 1</paper-item>
                        <paper-item>Topic 2</paper-item>
                        <paper-item>Topic 3</paper-item>
                    </paper-menu>
                </paper-submenu><paper-item class="menu-trigger">
                    Faves
                        <span class="flex layout horizontal end-justified">
                            <paper-menu-button on-tap="test">
                                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
                                <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
                                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[letters]]" as="letter">
                                        <paper-item>[[letter]]</paper-item>
                                    </template>
                                </paper-menu>
                            </paper-menu-button>
                        </span>
                </paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </div>
        
    </template>
</body>
<script>
    Demo.letters = [
      'alpha',
      'beta',
      'gamma',
      'delta',
      'epsilon'
    ];
    Demo.test = function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Here goes the problem: paper-menu-button does not react anymore as soon as the corresponding paper-item is focused (appears in gray).
I do not understand why the fact to be focused affect the inner paper-menu-button.

I have tried to stop the event bubbling but it does not change anything.
I am not even sure where the problem comes from, paper-menu behavior? Javascript event handling?

If anyone as a clue about what is the problem I could be great! Hoping to have been clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer: on focus a pseudo element after is displayed on the top of the item.
Once disabled through the --paper-menu-focused-item-after mixin, I can interact normally with my paper-menu-button